# How do I make a custom RegionFactory used by Hibernate Cache have Spring injected beans?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a class

```
public class SpringRedisRegionFactory extends RegionFactoryTemplate {

  @Autowired
  private transient RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

  @Override
  protected DomainDataStorageAccess createDomainDataStorageAccess(
      DomainDataRegionConfig regionConfig, DomainDataRegionBuildingContext buildingContext) {

    return registerNewStorageAccess(regionConfig.getRegionName());
  }
   ...

  private DomainDataStorageAccess registerNewStorageAccess(final String regionName) {

    if (storageAccesses == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("prepareForUse was not executed yet");
    }

    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this); // does not seem to work
    final var storageAccess = new SpringRedisStorageAccess(regionName, redisConnectionFactory);
    storageAccesses.add(storageAccess);
    return storageAccess;
  }
}
```

I get

> Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of SpringRedisRegionFactory: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application after the Spring WebApplicationContext has been initialized. Proceeding without injection.

I used a similar technique in EntityListeners but this does not appear to work with the `RegionFactory`

Answer (score 0):

I do know that Spring does have the `RedisConnectionFactory` since I can autowire it and see the value.  The issue is that it may not be available when the factory class is created by Hibernate, nor is it in the `ManagedBeanRegistry`

To work around it I have to simply store the value on initialization.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HibernateStorageConfiguration implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

  private static final AtomicReference<RedisConnectionFactory> configuredRedisConnectionFactoryRef =
      new AtomicReference<>();

  private final RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

  public static RedisConnectionFactory getConfiguredRedisConnectionFactory() {

    return configuredRedisConnectionFactoryRef.get();
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() {

    configuredRedisConnectionFactoryRef.set(redisConnectionFactory);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {

    configuredRedisConnectionFactoryRef.set(null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
> ```

I would think about something like:

```
public class SpringRedisRegionFactory extends RegionFactoryTemplate {

    private transient RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

    @Override
    protected void prepareForUse(SessionFactoryOptions settings, Map configValues) {
        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = settings.getServiceRegistry();
        ManagedBeanRegistry beanRegistry = serviceRegistry.requireService(ManagedBeanRegistry.class);
        redisConnectionFactory = beanRegistry.getBean(RedisConnectionFactory.class);
    }

... 

}
```

Comment: Where would something like this be documented?

Comment: also this occurs

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory': Could not resolve matching constructor on bean class [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory] (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities. You should also check the consistency of arguments when mixing indexed and named arguments, especially in case of bean definition inheritance)

Comment: I think this is presuming that the ManagedBeanRegistry is the same one provided by Spring  but that does not appear to be the case.

Comment: I tried getting the ApplicationContext from beanRegistry it also failed so likely it's not the same Spring bean container

Comment: `Could not resolve matching constructor on bean class` error means there was no bean implementing `RedisConnectionFactory` in spring context when JPA provider was initialising, and basically that is your responsibility to make it available.

Comment: It also fails on ApplicationConext the same way where it can't create it.  So it appears nothing is in the ManagedBeanRegistry.